# jquery подставить ссылку страницы

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log(window.location.href);
  $(".spldv2 p").hide();

  $('.spldv2 h3 a[href="http://test.ru/help"]').parent().next("p").show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="spldv2">
  <h3><a class="1" href="/help">Помощь</a></h3>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Пункт 1</a><br>
    <a href="#">Пункт 2</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Код отрабатывает нормально,но как только подставляю вместо явной ссылки сайта `window.location.href`, перестает работать.

`console.log` выдает `http://test.ru/help`

Может синтаксис другой ?

Делаю так:

```
$('.spldv2 h3 a[href="window.location.href"]').parent().next("p").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

На jquery можно изменить таким путём.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log(window.location.href);
        $(".spldv2 p").hide();
        $(".spldv2 h3 a[href]").attr("href", window.location.href);


    });

<div class="spldv2">
    <h3><a class="1" href="/help">Помощь</a></h3>
    <p >
        <a href="#">Пункт 1</a><br>
        <a href="#">Пункт 2</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Подскажи еще пожалуйста как присвоить h3 класс если находимся на этой странице ?

Comment: @Алексей Марченко, присвоить класс можно через 
        $(".spldv2 h3 a[href]").addClass('название_класса'); - Добавляет класс элементу.

Comment: Так он добавляет класс <a> , а мне нужно чтоб добавил к h3

Comment: $("h3").addClass('название_класса');

Comment: Так он добавляет класс ко всем h3, а мне нужно чтоб именно находясь на странице /help присвоил родителю h3
<h3><a class="1" href="/help">Помощь</a></h3>

Comment: Ахахахха, ну Вы даёте )))  if (document.location.pathname.indexOf("/test") === 0) {
            $(".spldv2 h3:first").addClass('название_класса');
        }

Comment: Или так. Если много может быть полей в начале $('.spldv2 h3 a').closest('h3').addClass('название_класса');

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.spldv2 h3 a[href="'+window.location.href+'"]').parent().next("p").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

нельзя в строку просто вписать переменную. js так не работает.
надо строки и переменные соединять +
Например:

```
var a = "строка"
var b  = 1;
b++;
var res = a + " " + b + " some";
alert(res); // строка 2 some
```